# Cannot access java.lang.String in script run in Rhino

Tags: java, javascript, string, rhino

I have problems accessing Java classes in JavaScript. Calling a code snippet

```
var String = Java.type("java.lang.String");
```

from Java via `javax.script.ScriptEngine`, yields follwing Error

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "Java" is not defined. (path/to/string.js#1) in path/to/string.js at line number 1
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:156)
    at main.JsTest.main(JsTest.java:55)
```

Using non-Java classes in the script works fine, e.g. `var value = a + b`, where `a` and `b` are defined in a `javax.script.ScriptContext`.

This is the Java class that executes the script.

**JsTest.java**

```java
public class JsTest
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    ScriptEngineManager sem = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine se = sem.getEngineByExtension("js");

    String script = "path/to/string.js";
    File scriptFile = new File(script);
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(scriptFile);

    se.put(ScriptEngine.FILENAME, script);

    ScriptContext sc = new SimpleScriptContext();
    se.eval(fr, sc);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea where your `Java.type` is coming from, but the [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Scripting_Java) uses `Packages.java` or just `java`.

So your line should probably look like

```
var String = Packages.java.lang.String;
```

Comment: Apparently I mixed in [Nashorn syntax](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Rhino+Migration+Guide).